# .htaccess redirection to an IP Address of a different server

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, mask, url-masking

I am hosting my public facing site at a shared host (Hostgator) with the domain pointing to the same. I also have my application hosted on a dedicated server with a different host. Both servers have their own SSL certificates installed.

Is there any way to edit the .htaccess file to do the following:

https://www.domain.com/CUSTOMER redirects to https://x.x.x.x/CUSTOMER while the browser still shows www.domain.com/CUSTOMER?

I'm vary of using frames due to the SSL ramifications. My domain registrar is Hostway and they do not offer URL masking/forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by making your server act as a proxy. Even if you have no access to the servers configuration you might be lucky that apaches proxy module is loaded: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html

If so you can 'map' the remote site (IP) as if being served by your normal server. 
Also apaches rewriting module can make use of that module by using the `[P]` flag in a `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have a copy of that site on the different server, preverally with the same database, so you don't get in trouble with i.e. order numbers or user logins between http and https. The certificate server must be the web server for your SSL provided web content.

[Take a look here foor further informations.](http://bit.ly/UAMB1f) "Google Search Result"